# How To Get Total Bugs From JIRA

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

i have a requirement to create a report. i need to get total bugs from jira. where can i get those bugs?

this is my formula

### Total Bugs found in PROD that should have been caught prior to PROD X 100

Total Bugs found in testing prior to PROD (by test team + others)

can anyone help on this

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

JQL: project = PROD and created <= prod-date

Answer (score 0):

project = yourprojectname AND created >= yyyy-mm-dd